# Leaflet Omnivore KML marker icons

Tags: javascript, leaflet, kml, mapbox

I am using leaflet, mapbox, and omnivore to build a map. I have a set of markers in a .kml file, which I'm able to load into leaflet using omnivore.

```
  leafletData.getMap('map').then(function(map) {
    var pointLayer = omnivore.kml('/kml/points-of-interest-places-to-eat-kml.kml').addTo(map)
    .on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
)
```

Each of these markers should have a style and icon associated with them in the .kml file:

```
<Style id="buildingLabel">
    <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
            <href>/icons/building-label.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
</Style>

<Placemark>
    <name>Building</name>
    <description>Building description</description>
    <styleUrl>#buildingLabel</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-78.893733888,43.944767691,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

The .kml file loads the markers fine, but they show up as generic markers and don't use the icon descibed in the .kml file (using the same file in Google maps they display fine).

How would I go about getting omnivore/leaflet to use these icons?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that Omnivore only imports the placemarks, not the style elements. Each feature still retains the `styleUrl` within its `properties`, but the corresponding reference is lost. How many separate styles are you dealing with? Is it feasible to hard-code the icon URLs?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did notice that the styleUrl had been retained in properties, but that's about as far as I've gotten. Unfortunately I actually have several different .kml files all with several styles associated with each.

Comment: One option would be to parse the kml file separately using something like [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js) (this is just the first xml to json converter I found with a web search; others may be better). You could then iterate over the resulting `Document.Style` array to find the `id` that matches your `styleUrl` for each feature. This is obviously less convenient than just using Omnivore, however.

Comment: Not a bad fallback, looks like that'll be my go to if I don't find anything else. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also notice that the [kml loader routine](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore/blob/master/leaflet-omnivore.js#L824) in Omnivore actually does load the styles, but it only applies `lineStyle` and `polyStyle`, not `iconStyle` (which seems like an unfortunate oversight). If you are comfortable editing the Omnivore code yourself, you could modify it to set the icon option for each marker, or at least to add the icon URL to the feature properties.

Comment: Can you try using a complete URL for the icon image, instead of the relative path?